# Serialization Exception when trying to fetch rows using Hibernate Criterea

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, serialization, criteria

I am trying to fetch rows from table `job_postings` which is mapped to java object `job` but for some reason I am getting following error

> ERROR com.zerosolutions.repository.access.JobDataAccess - org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize

Below is my Data Access Method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Job> getJobs(int companyId) {

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    List<Job> jobs = null;
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        logger.debug("before fetching jobs");
        jobs = session.createCriteria(Job.class).createAlias("company", "c")
                .add(Restrictions.eq("c.id", companyId)).list();

        tx.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e);
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return jobs;
}
```

Job Object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "job_postings")
public class Job {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "job_id")
private int jobId;

@Column(name = "heading")
private String heading;

@Column(name = "description")
private String description;

@Column(name = "date_posted")
private LocalDateTime datePosted;

@Column(name = "status")
private int status;

@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name = "company")
private Company company;

@Column(name = "location")
private String location;

@Column(name = "experience_req")
private String experienceReq;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "job")
private List<JobTags> tags = new ArrayList<>();

public int getJobId() {
    return jobId;
}

public void setJobId(int jobId) {
    this.jobId = jobId;
}

public String getHeading() {
    return heading;
}

public void setHeading(String heading) {
    this.heading = heading;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public LocalDateTime getDatePosted() {
    return datePosted;
}

public void setDatePosted(LocalDateTime datePosted) {
    this.datePosted = datePosted;
}

public int getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(int status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public Company getCompany() {
    return company;
}

public void setCompany(Company company) {
    this.company = company;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}

public String getExperienceReq() {
    return experienceReq;
}

public void setExperienceReq(String experienceReq) {
    this.experienceReq = experienceReq;
}

public List<JobTags> getTags() {
    return tags;
}

public void setTags(List<JobTags> tags) {
    this.tags = tags;
}
}
```

Error:

```
org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:243)
org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:287)
org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.fromBytes(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:138)
org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:113)
org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:27)
org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarbinaryTypeDescriptor.java:53)
org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:241)
org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:237)
org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:227)
org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:303)
org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2726)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1728)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1654)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1543)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:727)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2611)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2594)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2423)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2418)
org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:109)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1705)
org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:363)
com.zerosolutions.repository.access.JobDataAccess.getJobs(JobDataAccess.java:47)
com.zerosolutions.service.JobServices.getJobs(JobServices.java:19)
com.zerosolutions.controller.CompanyController.goCompanyPage(CompanyController.java:37)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:111)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71)

java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 32303135
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:806)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:309)
org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:299)
org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:218)
org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:287)
org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.fromBytes(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:138)
org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:113)
org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:27)
org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarbinaryTypeDescriptor.java:53)
org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:241)
org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:237)
org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:227)
org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:303)
org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2726)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1728)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1654)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1543)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:727)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2611)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2594)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2423)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2418)
org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:109)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1705)
org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:363)
com.zerosolutions.repository.access.JobDataAccess.getJobs(JobDataAccess.java:47)
com.zerosolutions.service.JobServices.getJobs(JobServices.java:19)
com.zerosolutions.controller.CompanyController.goCompanyPage(CompanyController.java:37)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:111)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71)
```

Any suggestions, what might me wrong ?

Is it due to java.time.LocalDateTime variable in class `Job` ?

Comment: @JonK But why it needs to be serialized in the first place ?

Comment: Are you detaching the entity at any point?

Comment: Please post a richer stack trace.

Comment: @DraganBozanovic added the error stack...take a look.